# getServerSideProps and mysql (RowDataPacket)

Tags: next.js, node-mysql

I'd like to do server side rendering with Next.js using the `getServerSideProps` method like [explained in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering).

The data should come from a database, so I'm using the `mysql` package. This results in the following error:

```
Error serializing `.assertions[0]` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/assertion". Reason: `object` ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

I think the reason for this is, because the `query` method from `mysql` returns special objects (`RowDataPacket`). The result that I'd like to pass to `getServerSideProps` looks like this when logged:

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, title: 'Test' } ]
```

I can fix this error by wrapping the result with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))` but this seems very odd to me.

So, my simple question is: **How to use `mysql.query` and `getServerSideProps` correctly?**

Or might this be an issue that should be addressed by `Next.js`?

Thank you

Answer (score 16):

I've run into this issue myself. When I had the issue it wasn't related to MySQL. The problem is `getServerSideProps()` expects you to return a "JSON serializable data type" which basically means a Plain ol' JavaScript Object ([POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object)).

To fix it, simply create a new POJO to return. A few ways you can go are:

```js
// using spread operator to create new object
const plainData = {
  ...queryResult
}

// recreating the object with plucked props
const plainData = {
  title: queryResult.title,
  content: queryResult.content
}

// data conversion (wax-on wax-off)
const plainData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(queryResult))
```

Your specific data is in an array so your simplest solution is the wax-on wax-off since it will support arrays. Otherwise you've got to map over it.

#### why tho?

You can see your object has `RowDataPacket` attached to it. This means it's an instance of  `RowDataPacket` and NextJS doesn't allow any instances unless it strictly equals the `Object.prototype` (see [related code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/96c3b087011f8395c887666c7593b48e2a85d4a6/packages/next/lib/is-serializable-props.ts#L9))

This seems weird, but they have already described why it's necessary [in a Github Issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11993#issuecomment-617937409). TL;DR dates cause issues client-side when the page hydrates.