# Encoding static imagery from public folder using getStaticProps in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, fs

Next.js [lays out a pretty comprehensive way](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#reading-files-use-processcwd) to get imagery from the `/public/` folder (where the app has you store static assets). The pattern is to use `fs` from Node and do the fetch in `getStaticProps`.

My attempt:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false, previewData }) {
  const cityData = dataFiltered.find( city => city.citySlug === params.slug )
  const cityMapImagePath = path.join(process.cwd(), `/public/static-maps/${cityData.imgPath}`)
  const cityMapImageRes = await fs.readFile(cityMapImagePath)
  const cityMapImageProcessed = JSON.stringify(cityMapImageRes)

  return {
    props: {
      preview,
      cityData: cityData,
      cityMapImage: cityMapImageProcessed
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

This code works, but it returns a pretty weird response when I reference that object in my component:

```js
<img src="{ "type":"Buffer", "data":[255,216,255,224,0,6,75,56,86,87,...] } />
```

My error has something to do with how I'm processing what `fs` gives me back. Do I need to encode my jpeg into `base64` to get Next to use it? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62671059/241153) suggests stringifying and then parsing (didn't work for me). Or maybe I need a [full blown endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727736/241153) to do this? Next isn't very clear on how to get *imagery* from getStaticProps into the component above it - perhaps you know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing for the fetch in `getStaticProps`:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false, previewData }) {
  const cityData = dataFiltered.find( city => city.citySlug === params.slug )
  const cityMapImagePath = path.join(process.cwd(), `/public/static-maps/${cityData.imgPath}`)
  let cityMapImageRes, cityMapImageProcessed

  try {
    cityMapImageRes = await fs.readFile(cityMapImagePath)
    cityMapImageProcessed = Buffer.from(cityMapImageRes).toString('base64')
  } catch {
    cityMapImageProcessed = null
  }

  return {
    props: {
      preview,
      cityData: cityData,
      cityMapImage: cityMapImageProcessed
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

Also make sure up in the component, you are properly encoding your image source as `base64` with the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix. This was a silly mistake that cost me an hour of debugging:

```js
<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${cityMapImage}`} alt='Alt text here' />
```

Finally, also note that Next.js when used with Vercel will impose a hard, [50MB cap (compressed) on the serverless function](https://vercel.link/serverless-function-size) used to process your `page` file request. If you're doing a `[slug].js` template, all the assets for EVERY page generated will count towards that cap. You'll hit it pretty fast on deploy, so double check yourself.

Update 2024-02: serverless bundle size can now go up to 250MB

Answer (score 2):

All data that is returned from the `getStaticProps` needs to be JSON serializable, so yes, if you want to return image there , you need to base64 encode it (this can be a problem for big images).
The other solution (if the scenario permits it) is not to do it with `getStaticProps` rather load the image on demand in the front end, by hitting the API after the page has already loaded.

Comment: Thanks, this got me thinking straight. I think I had two issues, not encoding in Base64 and then not prefixing my img src with the base64 encoding. I'll post a full answer below.